# Can I use env in preStop command

Tags: kubernetes

Can I use environment variable in lifecycle.preStop.exec.command? I have a script that has to be run in preStop command. The answer here states that it's possible to use env variables in postStart [Can I use env in postStart command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48150137/can-i-use-env-in-poststart-command). It doesn't work with preStop though. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

---

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: loap
spec: 
  replicas: 1
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: loap
    spec: 
      containers: 
        - 
          command: 
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - "echo $(date +%s): START >> /loap/timing; sleep 10; echo $(date +%s): END >> /loap/timing;"
          image: busybox
          env:
          - name: secretThing
            valueFrom:
              secretKeyRef:
                name: supersecret
                key: password
          lifecycle: 
            preStop: 
              exec: 
                command: 
                  - sh
                  - "-c"
                  - "echo ${secretThing} $(date +%s): PRE-HOOK >> /loap/timing"
          livenessProbe: 
            exec: 
              command: 
                - sh
                - "-c"
                - "echo $(date +%s): LIVENESS >> /loap/timing"
          name: main
          readinessProbe: 
            exec: 
              command: 
                - sh
                - "-c"
                - "echo $(date +%s): READINESS >> /loap/timing"
          volumeMounts: 
            - 
              mountPath: /loap
              name: timing
      initContainers: 
        - 
          command: 
            - sh
            - "-c"
            - "echo $(date +%s): INIT >> /loap/timing"
          image: busybox
          name: init
          volumeMounts: 
            - 
              mountPath: /loap
              name: timing
      volumes: 
        - 
          hostPath: 
            path: /tmp/loap
          name: timing
```

Comment: can you share your yaml file?

Comment: Updated my question with yaml file sample.

Comment: Can you try to use () instead of {}?

Comment: Tried both. Neither works for me.

Comment: can you try to output printenv both from your main pod and from preStop? from the documentation they suppose to run from the same container so you will probably need to see the same envs. if you still can't see the requested env - try to write it to file and source it fro the preStop

Comment: Thanks this helped identify the issue. I was using camel-case environment variables e.g. secretThing, instead should have used SECRET_THING. Do you know if it's documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the Kubernetes docs [Working with objects - Names](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/names/).

> A client-provided string that refers to an object in a resource URL, such as  `/api/v1/pods/some-name`.
>
> Only one object of a given kind can have a given name at a time. However, if you delete the object, you can make a new object with the same name.
>
> By convention, the names of Kubernetes resources should be up to maximum length of 253 characters and consist of lower case alphanumeric characters,  `-`, and  `.`, but certain resources have more specific restrictions.